# How to test async function in react using react-testing-librery

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am trying to use react testing library and writing common example, just to find out how it works.
And here is a problem, I have a component NewForm, there is a useEffect, and the purpose is to change state after 1 sec delay and show div with text. I need to write test to understand how to test async logic, but my solution is wrong, do you have any ideas how to fix it ?

My component:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

const NewForm = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(null)
  useEffect(() => {
   const timer =  setTimeout(() => {
      setValue({name: "Nik"})
    }, 1000)
    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timer)
    }
  }, [])
  return (
    <form>
        <input type="text" />
        <input type="email" />
        <button type={'button'}>Click</button>
        {value && <div>Div</div>}
    </form>
  )
}
```

My test file:

```
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react"
import NewForm from "./NewForm"


describe('', () => {
    it('', async () => {
        render(<NewForm/>)
        screen.debug()
        const divText =  await screen.findByText(/div/i)
        expect(divText).toBeInTheDocument()
        screen.debug()
    })
})
```

Error:

[image]

file setupTests:

`import '@testing-library/jest-dom'`

have no idea what to do

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try:

```
import { render, screen, act } from '@testing-library/react';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import React from 'react';
import NewForm from './NewForm';

describe('75915189', () => {
  it('should pass', async () => {
    jest.useFakeTimers();
    render(<NewForm />);
    act(() => {
      jest.advanceTimersByTime(1000);
    })
    const divText = await screen.findByText(/div/i);
    expect(divText).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

Test result:

```bash
 PASS  stackoverflow/75915189/NewForm.test.jsx (9.734 s)
  75915189
    ✓ should pass (41 ms)

-------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File         | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files    |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 NewForm.jsx |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
-------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        10.247 s
```